# Hex to dec conversion but little endian python

Tags: python, endianness

```
u16ModuleID_hex = f3.read(4)
u16ModuleID_dec = int(u16ModuleID_hex, 16)
```

This is how I converted `hex` to `dec`, but it turned out to be in `big endian` and I need `little endian`. I tried to use `struct` function but I get some problem, because:

```
u16ModuleID_hex - bytes
u16ModuleID_dec - int
f3 - txt file with bin to hex data 008002205a12f...
```

I got reversed number but not converted after I used this at the end:

```
u16ModuleID_dec = struct.pack('<H', u16ModuleID_dec)
```

If I put it in the middle i get:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'u16ModuleID_dec' referenced before assignment`

ex. `1500 = 21` instead `5376` which I get

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that the file contains a string representation of hexadecimal notation? If that's the case then you need to know whether it's 64, 32 or 16-bit. Once that's been clarified, it's just a question of swapping elements in a list

Answer (score 0):

Try with `bytearray`:

```
import struct

u16ModuleID_hex = "1500"
ba = bytearray.fromhex(u16ModuleID_hex)
ba.reverse()
u16ModuleID_dec = struct.unpack("<h", ba)

>>> u16ModuleID_dec
(5376,)
```

Comment: if i add it just like that i get: TypeError: fromhex() argument must be str, not bytes. I changed u16ModuleID_hex = str(f3.read(4)) and i get: ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1

Comment: u16ModuleID_hex is read from a file, not put manually

Comment: "1500 = 21 instead 5376" is the example you gave in your question. You should include a sample of your file if you need something else.